# How to pick out the date for a specific Action within an ID as well as the previous action

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a list of IDs, within each ID is multiple rows for different actions as well as an action date. I need to pick out the date of a specific action  as well as what action come prior to this one.

An example below;

| ID | Action | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | b | 01/02/2023 |
| 1 | c | 02/02/2023 |
| 1 | a | 03/02/2023 |
| 1 | d | 04/02/2023 |
| 2 | c | 01/02/2023 |
| 2 | b | 02/02/2023 |
| 2 | d | 03/02/2023 |
| 2 | a | 04/02/2023 |
| 3 | a | 01/02/2023 |
| 3 | d | 02/02/2023 |
| 3 | c | 03/02/2023 |
| 3 | b | 04/02/2023 |
| 4 | b | 01/02/2023 |
| 4 | a | 02/02/2023 |
| 4 | c | 03/02/2023 |
| 4 | d | 04/02/2023 |

Lets say I'm looking for Action `d`. Then:

for ID `1` I'd want to only have the row where action is `d` and `a`
for ID `2` rows where action `d` and `b`
for ID `3` rows where action `d` and `a`
for ID `4` rows where action `d` and `c`

I have no problem isolating just action d using `WHERE action = d` clause. I'm struggling to get the action before.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please add the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When asking questions like this you should be providing DDL and DML that produces your example data. This makes it much easier to help with your question.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT, Action CHAR(1), Date DATE)
INSERT INTO @Table (ID, Action, Date) VALUES
(1, 'b', '01/02/2023'), (1, 'c', '02/02/2023'), (1, 'a', '03/02/2023'), (1, 'd', '04/02/2023'), 
(2, 'c', '01/02/2023'), (2, 'b', '02/02/2023'), (2, 'd', '03/02/2023'), (2, 'a', '04/02/2023'), 
(3, 'a', '01/02/2023'), (3, 'd', '02/02/2023'), (3, 'c', '03/02/2023'), (3, 'b', '04/02/2023'), 
(4, 'b', '01/02/2023'), (4, 'a', '02/02/2023'), (4, 'c', '03/02/2023'), (4, 'd', '04/02/2023');
```

You want to select rows, where the action is `d`, and you're using a predicate in the where clause to do so, but you also want to return which ever action was most recently performed for that ID as well.

```
;WITH rowN AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) AS rn
  FROM @Table a
)

SELECT *
  FROM rowN a
    INNER JOIN rowN b
      ON a.id = b.ID
      AND a.rn = b.rn + 1
 WHERE a.Action = 'd'
```

Here we've used a windowed function to give each action a sequential number in a CTE. Since we now know we can expect the previous action to have a sequential number which is one less than the `d` action, we can simply just self join back to the CTE and find it.

| ID | Action | Date | rn | ID | Action | Date | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | d | 2023-04-02 | 4 | 1 | a | 2023-03-02 | 3 |
| 2 | d | 2023-03-02 | 3 | 2 | b | 2023-02-02 | 2 |
| 3 | d | 2023-02-02 | 2 | 3 | a | 2023-01-02 | 1 |
| 4 | d | 2023-04-02 | 4 | 4 | c | 2023-03-02 | 3 |

Comment: Thats perfect thanks! I'll improve my question writing in future.

Comment: Another option might be `Lag()` function. That would roll them up into the same row, which is not what was asked for, but sometimes that kind of thing can turn out to be even better.